# Bad local variable name

Tags: linux, bash

I created this function in a bash script:

```
gpio() {
  local folder = "/sys/class/gpio/gpio$1"
  if [ ! -d $folder ]
  then
    cd /sys/class/gpio
    echo $1 > export
    cd $folder
    echo out > direction
  fi
}
```

But I am getting this error:

```
local: /sys/class/gpio/gpio47: bad variable name
```

in the `local folder = "/sys/class/gpio/gpio$1"` line when I call it using `gpio 47`.

What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When assign value in bash you should not have space.
This:

```
local folder = "/sys/class/gpio/gpio$1"
```

Should become this

```
local folder="/sys/class/gpio/gpio$1"
```